# Angular Firebase retrive Data

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have Realtime database on Firebase.I am trying to fetch the data from the node
below is the image of my Realtime Database Firebase:-

[image]

I am trying to Fetch the Catagories Data into my Angular Project via following Code:-

```
getCatagories()
  {
    console.log("The Data is",this.db.list('/catagories').valueChanges());
    return this.db.list('/catagories');
  }
```

But when i print the data onto the Console it returns 
something like :-

[image]

How i can retrieve the data from Real time Firebase database and displayed onto the html view

I am attaching my Package.json file for angular project:-

```
{
  "name": "freelance-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^5.5.5",
    "firebase-tools": "^2.0.0",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

Please help to Retrieve the data
Thank you in advance

Comment: refer https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md

Comment: @rijin OP is using Firebase Realtime Database, so the documentation is on https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md. Sam: specifcally read https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#create-a-list-binding, which shows how to bind the data to your UI.

Comment: you will need to subscribe to the observer then map it.

Comment: Thank you guys the problem is solved by subscribing to the Observer.Thanks a lot for your help